# Variables are processsing DOM elements as null. Why is it happening?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In this code, I'm trying to assign DOM elements to variables, but variables get the value `null`. Why is it happening? Have I made some mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tasks</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A simple task list for your day-to-day.">
        <meta name="author" content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos">
        <meta name="keywords" content="task list, checklist">
        <script>
            var taskCreator = document.querySelector('#taskcreator');
            var list = document.querySelector('ul');
            var taskInput = document.querySelector('#taskinput');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul></ul>
        <input type="text" id="taskinput">
        <button id="taskcreator">Create new item</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code will be evaluated before the DOM is built. The elements your code looks for will not be in the DOM therefore. Move your `<script>` to just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Your script is executed **before** the dom content is created. Place your script at the end of your page

Comment: After you fix the loading issue, you have another issue. The code `list += '<li>' + taskInput.value + '</li>'` makes no sense. You are treating a DOM element as a string. That is NOT how you add elements to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browser executes your javascrit there is no input and button yet.
You can fix it with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tasks</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="A simple task list for your day-to-day.">
    <meta name="author" content="Bruno M. B. Sdoukos">
    <meta name="keywords" content="task list, checklist">
</head>
<body>
<ul></ul>
<input type="text" id="taskinput">
<button id="taskcreator">Create new item</button>
<script>
    var taskCreator = document.querySelector('#taskcreator');
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    var taskInput = document.querySelector('#taskinput');
    taskCreator.addEventListener('click', function createNewTask(event) {
        list.innerHTML += '<li>' + taskInput.value + '</li>'
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or wait in the script until whole file will have been parsed.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var taskCreator = document.querySelector('#taskcreator');
        var list = document.querySelector('ul');
        var taskInput = document.querySelector('#taskinput');
        taskCreator.addEventListener('click', function createNewTask(event) {
            list.innerHTML += '<li>' + taskInput.value + '</li>'
        })
    });
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: And that is still wrong... Two problems in the code, you fixed one.

Comment: Agree, there is two problems in the code. (list += '<li>' + taskInput.value + '</li>' - WRONG). But the second one was not a question. Any way thanks for your attention. I have edited my answer.